# Database Question with one-to-many relationship with default

Tags: mysql, database, one-to-many, default, one-to-one

I have a User table, and an Address table. The User can have many addresses, so the Address table entry has a foreign key to a User.

**My Question is**: The user can have many addresses, but can label only one as it main address (for shipping purposes). Is it better to add a foreign key to User named "main_address" which links to one of his addresses, or to add a column to the Address table named "is_main" (0 by default for all addresses, and 1 for the main address)? By better I mean speed and storage wise :)

EDIT: As suggested, I added the foreign key to User, but this is problematic. If the User and Address are not in the database yet, then it results in Circular dependency: A User can't be added without the Address, and the Address can't be added without the User. Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a foreign key on the `user` table, that is optional to avoid an interdependency that prevents adding records to either, is probably the cleaner solution. It avoids having to deal with preventing multiple main addresses for a user, takes less space, and makes joins to use the main address' information a little simpler.

Uniqueness is built in to foreign key the design. With an "is_main" design, the simplest prevention is making the field 1 or null (instead of 1 or 0) and putting a composite unique key on (user_id, is_main); and then to change the default you'd have to null out the old default before setting the new one to 1.

The foreign key field takes about a flat 4 bytes (assuming int pk for addresses, and ignoring nullability); is_main takes at least 1 byte for each address a user may have... if there are other bit fields, it could be smaller, but the space concerns are really trivial.

To get a user with their default address:

```
SELECT * 
FROM user AS u 
LEFT JOIN address AS a 
   ON u.main_address_id = a.address_id 
WHERE u.user_id = ?
;
```

vs

```
SELECT * 
FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN address AS a 
   ON u.user_id = a.user_id 
   AND a.is_main = 1 
WHERE u.user_id = ?
;
```

...that `AND is_main = 1` may seem like a trivial thing, and in a lot of cases it will be, but in a more complicated query it is the kind of thing that can mean not being to take of an index.

However, an upside to the is_main design: If you already have the user_id but not the main_address_id, you can get the main address information with a simple (no join) select from only the address table.

Comment: In the second query it should be `ON u.user_id = a.user_id`, since there is no `u.default_address_id` in this case.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I overlooked they already had a name for the field in mind... still like mine a little better though. ;) _will edit to main_address_id_

Comment: That's not what I mean. You don't need `u.default_address_id` if you have `a.is_main`.

Comment: What about: `insert into address (address_id, user_id) values (9, 1); update users set main_address_id = 9 where user_id = 2`? :-)

Comment: That is a bit more complicated, I'd maybe suggest `CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY main_address_fk (user_id, main_address_id) REFERENCES address(user_id, address_id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT`; but only with the restrictions. But even that feels a little dirty... probably a before update trigger that double checks would be cleaner.

Comment: I don't think you can let a part of the FK be nullable. The only "clean" solution I know, is to have a separate table `main_address` with unique `user_id` and a refference to `address` table.

Comment: Wait.. So if I have to add a new user with a new address? I need the User ID to add an Address, but don't have it yet since I need to save the User, but when I save the User, I need the Address ID, which I don't have! Seems like circular dependency. EDIT: I think @PaulSpiegel 's answer would solve this circular dependency.

Comment: The circular dependency is not a problem if the foreign key is optional (nullable) as I said in my first sentence; but yeah, the composite foreign key I put in the comments was just an idea thrown out there. Realistically, I'd expect UI and business logic to prevent a user's main address from referencing an address of another user (i.e. only let whoever determines the main address to select from that user's addresses.)